# Why canvas Draw slowly when real time plot values graph?

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-studio, canvas

I want to draw line using sample values from array or real time plot values from external device. i almost got ans. But  there is canvas not draw even speed from start to end point. after executing some data canvas almost dead slow. please suggest me what is the problem inside the ondraw method...

```
public class WaveDrawing extends View {

    public final Paint backgroundColor = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    public final Paint patientData = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    public final Paint patientDataRePaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

    int i = 0; //k = 36;

    //graph point
    int[] a = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34, 36, 38, 40, 42, 44, 46, 48, 50, 0, 0, -40, -38, -36, -34, -32, -30, -28, -26, -24, -22, -20, -18, -16, -14, -12, -10, -8, -6, -4, -2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 32, 26, 40, 44, 48, 50, -25, -20, -15, -10, -5, -0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 32, 36, 40, 44, 48, 54, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 6, 6, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, -50, -48, -46, -44, -42, -40, -38, -36, -34, -32, -30, -28, -26, -24, -22, -20, -18, -16, -14, -12, -10, -8, -6, -4, -2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, -2, -2, -3, -3, -4, -4, -5, -5, -6, -6, -7, -6, -6, -5, -5, -4, -4, -3, -3, -2, -2, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0
    ,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34, 36, 38, 40, 42, 44, 46, 48, 50, 0, 0, -40, -38, -36, -34, -32, -30, -28, -26, -24, -22, -20, -18, -16, -14, -12, -10, -8, -6, -4, -2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 32, 26, 40, 44, 48, 50, -25, -20, -15, -10, -5, -0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 32, 36, 40, 44, 48, 54, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 6, 6, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, -50, -48, -46, -44, -42, -40, -38, -36, -34, -32, -30, -28, -26, -24, -22, -20, -18, -16, -14, -12, -10, -8, -6, -4, -2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, -2, -2, -3, -3, -4, -4, -5, -5, -6, -6, -7, -6, -6, -5, -5, -4, -4, -3, -3, -2, -2, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0
    ,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34, 36, 38, 40, 42, 44, 46, 48, 50, 0, 0, -40, -38, -36, -34, -32, -30, -28, -26, -24, -22, -20, -18, -16, -14, -12, -10, -8, -6, -4, -2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 32, 26, 40, 44, 48, 50, -25, -20, -15, -10, -5, -0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 32, 36, 40, 44, 48, 54, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 6, 6, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, -50, -48, -46, -44, -42, -40, -38, -36, -34, -32, -30, -28, -26, -24, -22, -20, -18, -16, -14, -12, -10, -8, -6, -4, -2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, -2, -2, -3, -3, -4, -4, -5, -5, -6, -6, -7, -6, -6, -5, -5, -4, -4, -3, -3, -2, -2, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0
    ,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34, 36, 38, 40, 42, 44, 46, 48, 50, 0, 0, -40, -38, -36, -34, -32, -30, -28, -26, -24, -22, -20, -18, -16, -14, -12, -10, -8, -6, -4, -2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 32, 26, 40, 44, 48, 50, -25, -20, -15, -10, -5, -0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 32, 36, 40, 44, 48, 54, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 6, 6, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, -50, -48, -46, -44, -42, -40, -38, -36, -34, -32, -30, -28, -26, -24, -22, -20, -18, -16, -14, -12, -10, -8, -6, -4, -2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, -2, -2, -3, -3, -4, -4, -5, -5, -6, -6, -7, -6, -6, -5, -5, -4, -4, -3, -3, -2, -2, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0
    ,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34, 36, 38, 40, 42, 44, 46, 48, 50, 0, 0, -40, -38, -36, -34, -32, -30, -28, -26, -24, -22, -20, -18, -16, -14, -12, -10, -8, -6, -4, -2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 32, 26, 40, 44, 48, 50, -25, -20, -15, -10, -5, -0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 32, 36, 40, 44, 48, 54, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 6, 6, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, -50, -48, -46, -44, -42, -40, -38, -36, -34, -32, -30, -28, -26, -24, -22, -20, -18, -16, -14, -12, -10, -8, -6, -4, -2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, -2, -2, -3, -3, -4, -4, -5, -5, -6, -6, -7, -6, -6, -5, -5, -4, -4, -3, -3, -2, -2, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0
    ,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34, 36, 38, 40, 42, 44, 46, 48, 50, 0, 0, -40, -38, -36, -34, -32, -30, -28, -26, -24, -22, -20, -18, -16, -14, -12, -10, -8, -6, -4, -2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 32, 26, 40, 44, 48, 50, -25, -20, -15, -10, -5, -0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 32, 36, 40, 44, 48, 54, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 6, 6, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, -50, -48, -46, -44, -42, -40, -38, -36, -34, -32, -30, -28, -26, -24, -22, -20, -18, -16, -14, -12, -10, -8, -6, -4, -2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, -2, -2, -3, -3, -4, -4, -5, -5, -6, -6, -7, -6, -6, -5, -5, -4, -4, -3, -3, -2, -2, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0
    ,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34, 36, 38, 40, 42, 44, 46, 48, 50, 0, 0, -40, -38, -36, -34, -32, -30, -28, -26, -24, -22, -20, -18, -16, -14, -12, -10, -8, -6, -4, -2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 32, 26, 40, 44, 48, 50, -25, -20, -15, -10, -5, -0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 32, 36, 40, 44, 48, 54, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 6, 6, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, -50, -48, -46, -44, -42, -40, -38, -36, -34, -32, -30, -28, -26, -24, -22, -20, -18, -16, -14, -12, -10, -8, -6, -4, -2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, -2, -2, -3, -3, -4, -4, -5, -5, -6, -6, -7, -6, -6, -5, -5, -4, -4, -3, -3, -2, -2, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0
    ,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34, 36, 38, 40, 42, 44, 46, 48, 50, 0, 0, -40, -38, -36, -34, -32, -30, -28, -26, -24, -22, -20, -18, -16, -14, -12, -10, -8, -6, -4, -2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 32, 26, 40, 44, 48, 50, -25, -20, -15, -10, -5, -0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 32, 36, 40, 44, 48, 54, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 6, 6, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, -50, -48, -46, -44, -42, -40, -38, -36, -34, -32, -30, -28, -26, -24, -22, -20, -18, -16, -14, -12, -10, -8, -6, -4, -2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, -2, -2, -3, -3, -4, -4, -5, -5, -6, -6, -7, -6, -6, -5, -5, -4, -4, -3, -3, -2, -2, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0
    ,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34, 36, 38, 40, 42, 44, 46, 48, 50, 0, 0, -40, -38, -36, -34, -32, -30, -28, -26, -24, -22, -20, -18, -16, -14, -12, -10, -8, -6, -4, -2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 32, 26, 40, 44, 48, 50, -25, -20, -15, -10, -5, -0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 32, 36, 40, 44, 48, 54, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 6, 6, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, -50, -48, -46, -44, -42, -40, -38, -36, -34, -32, -30, -28, -26, -24, -22, -20, -18, -16, -14, -12, -10, -8, -6, -4, -2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, -2, -2, -3, -3, -4, -4, -5, -5, -6, -6, -7, -6, -6, -5, -5, -4, -4, -3, -3, -2, -2, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0
    ,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34, 36, 38, 40, 42, 44, 46, 48, 50, 0, 0, -40, -38, -36, -34, -32, -30, -28, -26, -24, -22, -20, -18, -16, -14, -12, -10, -8, -6, -4, -2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 32, 26, 40, 44, 48, 50, -25, -20, -15, -10, -5, -0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 32, 36, 40, 44, 48, 54, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 6, 6, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, -50, -48, -46, -44, -42, -40, -38, -36, -34, -32, -30, -28, -26, -24, -22, -20, -18, -16, -14, -12, -10, -8, -6, -4, -2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, -2, -2, -3, -3, -4, -4, -5, -5, -6, -6, -7, -6, -6, -5, -5, -4, -4, -3, -3, -2, -2, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0
    };

    //int pre, next;
    public WaveDrawing(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public WaveDrawing(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public WaveDrawing(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    public void init() {
       // backgroundColor.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        patientData.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        patientDataRePaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        patientData.setStrokeWidth(2);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        int widthIterator = 0;

        //canvas.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), backgroundColor);

        if (i != 0) {

            for (int drawPulseIterator = 1; drawPulseIterator <= i; drawPulseIterator++) {

                if (widthIterator > getWidth() ) {
                    widthIterator = 0;
                   // k = widthIterator;
                } else {
                    widthIterator += 1;
                }

                canvas.drawRect(widthIterator, 0, widthIterator + 7, getHeight(), patientDataRePaint);
                canvas.drawLine(widthIterator, (getHeight() / 2) - a[drawPulseIterator], widthIterator + 1, (getHeight() / 2) - a[drawPulseIterator - 1], patientData);
            }
        }
        i++;
        if (i == a.length) {
            i = 1;

        }

        invalidate();
    }
}
```

XML

```
<com.test.sample.wave.WaveDrawing
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: drawPulseIterator<= a.length instead of drawPulseIterator <= i in your loop would save  you a couple of lines.

Comment: loop is executed twenty times speed compare to canvas. i want draw line evenly for loop values and canvas. how can i improve canvas speed - @eldo

Comment: I wasnt really talking about your performance issue, i just suggested some improvements you are iterating while drawPulseIterator is <= a.lenght either way, just wanted to spare you a couple line. About your performance, you are drawing a lot of rectangles and lines, consider using openGL as mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

In the `onDraw` method, there is an increase of loop iterations. This leads to the fact that it is necessary to do more work per pass rendering cycle. Also your animation depends on the device performance. So for more powerful devices, the animation will go faster.In general, using `onDraw()` and `invalidate()` to draw dynamic graphics - bad idea. For these purposes it is better to use the OpenGL ES. For the same performance on different devices, the animation is better to make time-dependent rendering between frames

Answer (score 0):

There is another way. You can draw your pulse line in Bitmap. then draw bitmap on main Canvas:

```
    @Override
    public synchronized void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        if (!mIsInited) {
            int w = getWidth(), h = getHeight();
            Bitmap.Config conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
            mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, conf);
            mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
            mCanvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
            mIsInited = true;
        }

        if (i != 0) {

            if (mWidthIterator > getWidth()) {
                mWidthIterator = 0;
            } else {
                mWidthIterator += 1;
            }

            mCanvas.drawRect(mWidthIterator, 0, mWidthIterator + 7, getHeight(), patientDataRePaint);
            mCanvas.drawLine(mWidthIterator, (getHeight() / 2) - a[i], mWidthIterator + 1, (getHeight() / 2) - a[i - 1], patientData);
        }
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, null);
        i++;
        if (i == a.length) {
            i = 1;
            mWidthIterator = 0;
            mCanvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        }

        invalidate();
    }
```

Also, do not forget to make mWidthIterator, mCanvas and mBitmap as an instance variables.

Comment: Canvas going to draw runtime line not group of values. if possible to draw one by one plot point [array value].

Comment: The above code is doing what makes your code. But without the extra work during rendering, which eliminates performance degradation at runtime. I don't  understand what you want, if it is not the answer to your question.